# Text find and replace in Word document with Execute command from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I found standard code for finding and replacing text in a Word document.

The document is opened and the text is found.

Execution of the replacement is not working.

```
Sub tester()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True

    template = "template2"
    templateFold = "C:\MyFolder\test\test2\"

    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(templateFold & template & ".docx")

     With WordApp.Selection.Find
        .Text = "Dear"
        .Replacement.Text = "Hello"
        .Forward = True
        .NoProofing = True
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try with .Execute Forward:=True ?

Comment: Silly, but try putting `.Forward = True` as the first thing (above `.Text = "Dear"`).  Or, don't you mean ` With WordDoc.Selection.Find`?

Comment: Sadly, both are not working ...

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN's [Finding and Replacing Text or Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx) your code only selects the text instead of replacing it.

Your code should be something like this:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Dear"
    .Replacement.Text = "Hello"
    .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Could it be something wrong with my excel parameters or my environment ?

Comment: I tried this and it works for me as well so it might be, indeed, due to something other from the code...

Answer (score 0):

`Execute` on its own doesn't do anything. You have to wrtite `Replace:=wdReplaceAll` or `Replace:=wdReplaceOne` after 
`.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll`
You also need to add `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` before executing